# Is it possible to give a different hostname than xmcloudcm.localhost to the xmcloud docker container?

Tags: docker, xm-cloud

By default the CM_HOST value in the `init.ps1` file of a XM Cloud project is set to `xmcloud.localhost`. I want to change this name to, for example `xmcloudserge.loca.lt`.

If I change the name I get a problem with the authentication from `https://xmcloudserge.local.lt` to sitecorecloud.io, which contains a hard reference to `xmcloud.localhost` as a return URL:

`https://auth.sitecorecloud.io/authorize?client_id=we67e2gGRO0HIfglz23Yypp4T5Rshu86&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DE7FEVVpMc5sJM8SLjOlOU_m73gkTqvOfFxs2LrcnaZdSrX3MRF_Q12ZyVDpbKIXZhDDWImasq51g1-y5BGIXOsq21vxGGb8FJjz12NttbaecPcQ8z9Kd0Fnrv5yZmRk0Fjf3TntIMUw2WT628TXtyfEeHhJ8gbaem0rO08GVln8TwzKDJR4qEg7nxqEbucvf7Bt1KMCg_FjD0VdxC2m1hq0WEZ5zfKLTTf_fYOg0-d0&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638012677311361499.Y2ZmMWYzMjUtNjRkZS00NDJjLWI0YzctZjZmZWNmOWUyZWRiZGIwZGE5NzEtNDYwMS00YmU0LWJlMzItZTU5MWVmNDc5MDBj&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxmcloudcm.localhost%2Fidentity%2Fsignin-auth0&organization_id=&returnTo=https%3A%2F%2Fxmcloudcm.localhost%2Fsitecore&x-client-SKU=ID_NET461&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0`

If I change the `returnTo` query-string parameter to `https://xmcloudserge.local.lt` I get the following error:

```
Callback URL mismatch.

The provided redirect_uri is not in the list of allowed callback URLs.

Please go to the Application Settings page and make sure you are sending a valid callback url from your application.
```

which sounds logical, because the return URL must be whitelisted.

The reason I want to do this is because I want the Sitecore container to be accessible to the outside world, for example by using a local tunnel with the tool `localtunnel` as follows:

```
lt --local-host xmcloudserge.loca.lt --port 443 --allow-invalid-cert --local-https -s xmcloudserge
```

Which should result in the URL `https://xmcloudserge.loca.lt` mapped to the same URL on my local machine.

Any ideas to accomplish this are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Why do you need the CM container to be accessible to the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

It is not possible to change the default url of `xmcloudcm.localhost` - this is a restriction as you expected, that the url must be whitelisted for the auth0 redirects. Because the authentication provider is hosted by Sitecore, it would not be scalable to add every combination of development url into the whitelist, so there is just this one that you can use for local development.

If you want to have an instance of XM Cloud exposed to the outside world, it would be better to create a new environment in your XM Cloud project and use that.

Comment: that is the biggest problem... no access to an XM Cloud environment (yet):-) So try to hack my way around that...

Comment: Wrote a blogpost on my (failed) experiments in this direction at https://www.sergevandenoever.nl/XM_Cloud_container_nofiddle/